# Ruby binary search

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to do a binary search on a list of 1 million employee IDs, already sorted out.

```
def exist?(id)
  lower = -1
  upper = $employee_list.count
  while true
    mid = (lower + upper) / 2
    if upper == lower + 1
      return nil
      if id == $employee_list[mid]
        return mid
        if id < $employee_list[mid]
          upper = mid
        else
          lower = mid
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I get the error:

```
NoMethodError:undefined method 'call' for nil:NilClass
```

Also, I'm trying to make it such that if `exist?(54)` is in the list, it will return `true`.

Comment: There's no `call` here.

Comment: I can understand why, as an exercise, you might want to write code to do a binary search, but the mention of "1 million employee IDs" suggests it's a task for an actual app. If so, why would you reinvent the wheel, rather than just searching with a database or using Ruby's built-in  [Array#bsearch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch) method? That method was introduced in v2.0, but I'm sure there must be many gems that provide the same functionality for earlier versions.

Comment: "keep getting the error" brings a smile to my face, as it's something we've all experienced: when seemingly correct code doesn't work, we just run it again, unchanged, and strangely get the same wrong answer or error message.

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`Array#bsearch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch):

```
$employee_list.bsearch { |employee| id <=> employee }
```

As for the error - it comes from somewhere else.